# Failing an NUnit test inside teardown

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I have a bunch of automated UI tests running with selenium and NUnit.

After every nunit test I want to check the browser for any JS errors that have occurred. If there are any JS errors the test that caused them should fail. I want this to run for all tests I write without having to copy the check into each test.

I also take screenshots on any failure.

```
    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        Assert.Fail("Some JS error occurred"); //This is to simulate a JS error assertion

        if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status != TestStatus.Passed)
        {
            Driver.TakeScreenshot(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name, "Failed");
        }
    }
```

If I fail an assertion inside teardown it will never execute the screenshot code (as the assert is an exception).

**Is there a better way to fail the test here so that I can carry on with my logic?**

Comment: Why are you calling a fail assert?

Comment: @steve "After each test I want to check the browser for any JS errors that have occurred and if there are any fail the test" I will  clarify the code a little

Comment: I still don't understand why you are calling this in the teardown? Wouldn't you have a standard test to check for JS errors and call fail there?

Comment: @steve i want to check for JS errors after every test that executes. I'm not sure what you mean by a 'standard test'.

Comment: +1 for @Steve question and why are you making screenshot on `test status` equals passed. For me it makes more sense to make a screenshot on test failure.

Comment: @drets huh? `TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status != TestStatus.Passed`

Comment: right, sorry, need to go to sleep :)

Comment: @drets If i move the assertion to the test body everything would work just fine. However I want to do this after every single test I do and I dont want to have to copy (or remember to copy) this assertion into every test

Comment: right now it makes sense, thanks, +1 :)

Comment: @drets Sweet ill see if i can modify my wording to be more clear i seem to be confusing people :)

Comment: @drets does that read a little clearer now?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor I think I understand, see my answer for a possible solution.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor if your issue only with screenshots can you just don't use `Assert.Fail` and use flag instead. E.g. `jsErrorsOccured` and use it like following: `if (jsErrorsOccured || (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status != TestStatus.Passed)) { ... }` ?

Comment: For me it looks like you want to find out the way how to set up `TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status` manually (not in typical way) :-)
am I right?

Comment: @drets yeah manipulating test status is really what im after, I currently work around the issue exactly as you are describing but its a bit messy and i feel like there should be a better way

Comment: @LukeMcGregor hard way: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/testing-times-ahead-extending-nunit/ :P

Comment: @drets lol wow i guess that would solve the problem... Im getting the feeling not failing and using a bool in my tear down is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

You could extend your own `TestActionAttribute` that runs your JS tests. If an assertion failure is thrown in `AfterTest()`, NUnit seems to report the test as being failed.

E.g. this:

```
[CheckForJSErrors] // your custom attribute - applies to all tests
public class ClassTest
{
    [Test]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        // Your test case
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class CheckForJSErrorsAttribute : TestActionAttribute
{
    public override void AfterTest(TestDetails testDetails)
    {
        // if you only want to check for JS errors if the test passed, then:
        if(TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status == TestStatus.Passed)
        {
            Driver.TakeScreenshot(testDetails.FullName, "Failed");
            Assert.Fail("Some JS error occurred"); //This is to simulate a JS error assertion
        }
    }
    public override ActionTargets Targets
    {
        // explicitly says to run this after each test, even if attr is defined on the entire test fixture
        get { return ActionTargets.Test; }
    }
}
```

Produces this failure in NUnit:

`SO_34306757.ClassTest.MyTest:
TearDown : NUnit.Framework.AssertionException : Some JS error occurred`

I've declared the `[CheckForJSErrors]` attribute for the entire test fixture to avoid having to declare it on every test case, but you could declare it per test method if you want.

Comment: This is quite a good way of checking, i like it more than a base class. But I only want to take a screenshot on failure of either the test or detection of a JS error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the same thing after every test, you could just right a common method that you call in each test itself. That way you're not duplicating the test code and you are keeping the fail assert out of the tear down.

Eg.

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    // sometest code
    TestJS();
}

[Test]
public void Test2()
{
    // some other test code
    TestJS();
}

public void TestJS()
{
    Assert.Fail("Or whatever to test the JS");
}

[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status != TestStatus.Passed)
    {
        Driver.TakeScreenshot(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name, "Failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that would work but its not very DRY, it requires me to remember to put TestJS at the end of each test. In reality this is in a base class with a lot of tests hanging off it. I would much rather do this in teardown.